# Expose as much information as possible on 3 unknown database files

Tags: mysql, sql, database, file, ms-access

So we got an old program, from about 2006-2007.
that program uses a very large database.
the database is separated into 3 files:
(file extensions were renamed.)

- 1 of 1,061,758,976 bytes
- 1 of 1,062,225,920 bytes
- and 1 of 423,604,224 bytes

(total about 2.4 GB).

what we want to do is get rid of that program and write our own, using the same database.
the only problem is that we don't know anything about those files. Rumors says that those files are access files - but we don't know how to confirm that.

also, the goal is to put this whole database into a mySQL database - which is another challenge.

Summarizing:

- Determine database type
- Converting to mySQL.

Any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: File header:

[image]

Comment: What are the files called?

Comment: They changed the file extensions - forgot to mention that.

Comment: It will be very difficult with so little information.   What is the name of the old program?  Can you open any of the files in a binary editor.   Often, the first few bytes in the file help determine the file type....

Comment: @Sparky Does it helps you? [Binary screenshot](http://s13.postimg.org/vo13f16w7/Untitled.png)

Comment: That looks very like an mdb, that is, pre-2007 MS Access database. If you copy the file and rename it to give an mdb extension, you should be able to import it into MySql. For example http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html

Comment: Yep, it does, but looks like Gord has a great answer for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Determine database type

The screenshot cited in the comments to the question indicate that the file is an Access `.mdb` database file. Access database files contain the following 15-character strings starting at byte offset 4:

`Standard Jet DB` ...for an .mdb file
`Standard ACE DB` ...for an .accdb file

> Converting to mySQL.

The most straightforward way would be to install the MySQL ODBC driver, create an ODBC DSN to the target MySQL server, then open the .mdb file in Access and export the tables to MySQL via ODBC.

[Exporting Access Data to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-access-export.html)

**edit re: "You do not have the necessary permissions..." error**

It appears that the database file was encrypted using the "User-Level Security" feature that Access offered for older .mdb files. If so, then to open the file you will need:

1. The associated Workgroup Security file (often called "Security.mdw", but may have a different name)
2. Login credentials (username and password) for a user that was created in that Workgroup file.

If you have both of those prerequisites then you should be able to open the file using something like the following from the command-line:

```
MSACCESS.EXE "C:\Users\Public\uls\db1.mdb" /WRKGRP "C:\Users\Public\uls\Security.mdw"
```

Search around to see if you can find the associated .mdw file (possibly renamed). Note that if if you find a file named `System.mdw` under `%SystemRoot%` or `%APPDATA%` ***it may not be the one you need***. (Access creates a default Workgroup file for normal unprotected databases.) The file you are looking for should have a similar 15-character string starting at byte offset 4:

`Jet System DB` ...for an .mdw file (note that there are two trailing spaces to make 15 characters)

Comment: Thank you!
now there's another issue : when attempting to open each file we get an error message: `"you do not have the necessary permissions to use the mdb object"`. using Microsoft Access 2007.

Comment: Thank you.
So I guess that without the .mdw file or its values it is not possible to use that data? nothing can be with the original program to expose those values?

Comment: @user2216190 To open the database file yourself you definitely need the .mdw file and the proper credentials. Depending on what "the original program" actually is, you *might* be able to reveal some useful information by opening it (i.e., the program itself) in your hex editor. Failing that, there are probably some file-recovery services out there that could take a stab at cracking the database files, but I have no experience with any of them.